# Selenium IDE and Xpath object recognition

Tags: object, xpath, selenium, firebug

I am new to Selenium and world of testing. 
I have a query on identifying the objects using XPath/Firebug. I have a tree view which has folders and files when I click on any folder it recognizes with Node6...[n] etc. but I want to identify as its name and not Node. Here is the quick HTML code -

```
<a name="Node6" id="Node6" href="JAVASCRIPT:NodeClick(6, false );">Laptop Test</a>
<a name="Node7" id="Node7" href="JAVASCRIPT:NodeClick(7, false );">Laptop Main</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the following xpath:

```
//a[@name='Node6']
```

or

```
//a[text()='Laptop Test']
```

Comment: when I try this I get the following error - 

[error] Unexpected Exception: TypeError: inWindow.frames[i] is undefined. fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js, lineNumber -> 1489, columnNumber -> 0


I am giving Command as 'clickAndWait' Target =//a[text()='Laptop'] Value = <blank - nothing i have entered here>

Comment: Why `//a[text()='Laptop']`  and not `//a[text()='Laptop Test']`?

Comment: Try to use `clickAndWait xpath=//a[text()='Laptop Test']`, actually I am not familiar with selenium IDE, you should check syntax.

Comment: Sorry for the typo and I used 'Laptop Test' only. 
Now when I use xpath=//a[text()='Laptop Test'], it is able to now recognize the object but not able to click on it. When I use clickAndWait it throws this error - 

[error] Unexpected Exception: TypeError: inWindow.frames[i] is undefined. fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js, lineNumber -> 1489, columnNumber -> 0

Comment: Try to add timeout before click. If that won't help, try to use another version of web browser or selenium. Or just google this problem.

Comment: Tried that as well but doesn't help. Still stuck! :(